# Cannot centralize cocos2d-js game

Tags: javascript, alignment, screen-resolution, cocos2d-js

I have made a game that is designed for 1136x768 resolution in cocos2d js. I have given design resolution as 1136x768 and FIXED_HEIGHT resolution policy.

```
cc.view.setDesignResolutionSize(1136, 768, cc.ResolutionPolicy.FIXED_HEIGHT);
```

I have given fixed height as I need to display the whole height of game and width can be adjusted accordingly. The result I get looks like this:

[image]

I need my game area to be centralized in screen and I do not know how to do this since I an new to Javascript. Can anyone tell me how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Normally there shouldn't be a black bar on any of these sides, even when using fixed height in landscape.
However, I assume that some of your layers uses fixed sizing. I just added a cc.LayerColor as my background layer and it then covered the whole screen, no matter which mode I'm using.
Maybe you'll also have to add:

```
cc.view.resizeWithBrowserSize(true);
```

to get rid of the black bar.